# How can I install objdump on Mac OS X?

Tags: linux, macos, dump

I want to get the source code of a small command line tool using objdump on Mac OS X.

I've used arm-linux-objdump on Linux and find it a great tool.

Is there any way to install objdump on OS X? I've searched Google and found information about arm-apple-dawin9-objdump, but failed to find anything to download.

Answer (score 60):

`objdump` is part of [binutils](http://binutils.darwinports.com/).

Comment: Homebrew has it too! :)

Comment: I was hoping homebrew has it! Thanks! 
`brew install binutils`

Comment: MacPorts binutils installs `objdump` as `gobjdump`.

Comment: `-bash: objdump: command not found`

Comment: ```brew install binutils``` also installs it as gobjdump

Answer (score 33):

If you have XCode Tools installed on your Mac, you can use the [otool](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/otool.1.html) that comes with it. I believe it does pretty much what `objdump` is capable of.

Comment: +1 for otool - use `otool -tV <executable>` to disassemble

Comment: `dwarftool` also offers some similar functionality.

Comment: does otool have an option like objdump -S, which gives assembly output annotated with source code? Couldn't really figure out from the --help output.

Comment: `-bash: dwarftool: command not found`

Answer (score 8):

If your file is 64bits, you should use **otool** instead of **gobjdump** from **binutils**. On Mac OSX, gobjdump is for 32bits.

Comment: As of 2017, gobjdump 2.27 (I think I got it from homebrew?) does work well with 64 bits in macOS Sierra (10.12)

Answer (score 7):

You can install it with Homebrew:

```
$ brew install binutils
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/binutils-2.25.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring binutils-2.25.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/binutils/2.25: 107 files, 140M
$ which gobjdump
/usr/local/bin/gobjdump
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `otool` because `objdump` is a binutils tool for the ELF binary format on Linux and most other UNIX systems. `otool` is the the disassembler for MacOS's Mach-O binary format. Type `$ man otool` for instructions on use.

Answer (score 0):

After `binutils` installation through `brew install binutils`, if you still can not find `gobjdump` in your $PATH, the reason perhaps is that `homebrew` forgot to create soft link to the binary.

```
$ cd /opt/homebrew/bin

// $ ls -l ../Cellar/binutils/2.37/bin/gobjdump
// lrwxr-xr-x  1 steve  admin  7 Jul 19  2021 ../Cellar/binutils/2.37/bin/gobjdump -> objdump

// change this command to fit your objdump binary path
$ link ../Cellar/binutils/2.37/bin/gobjdump  gobjdump
```

My environment:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin localhost 20.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.5.0: Sat May  8 05:10:31 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.121.3~9/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 arm64
$ brew --version
Homebrew 3.4.3
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 1f841cb3044; last commit 2022-03-27)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 60208d8c20; last commit 2022-03-26)
```